# StackOverFlow occuring in divide and conquer problem : maximum subArray

Tags: java

I was trying to resolve the maximum subArray sum problem with the divide and conquer approach but a runTime error (StackOverFlow) occured and I have no idea how to handle it, I think it's occuring just because of my recursive calls. Here is my approach (the error occured at the first recursive line):

```
class Solution {

    public int maxSubArray(int[] nums){
        int length = nums.length;
         int middle = length / 2;
         if(length == 1) {
             return nums[0];
         }

         int[] starting = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 0, middle+1);
         int[] ending = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, middle +1, length);

         int left = maxSubArray(starting);
         int right = maxSubArray(ending);
         int crossing = computeCrossingSum(starting,ending);

         int result = Math.max(left,right);
         int finalResult = Math.max(result,crossing);

         return finalResult;
     }

     public int computeCrossingSum (int[] left, int[]right){

         int leftS =Integer.MIN_VALUE;
         int rightS =Integer.MIN_VALUE;
         int leftIndex;
         int rightIndex;

         int sumS = 0;
         for(int i = left.length -1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
             sumS += left[i];
             if (sumS > leftS) {
                 leftS = sumS;
                 leftIndex = i;
             }
         }


         int sumA = 0;
         for(int i = 0 ; i< right.length ; i++){
             sumA+=right[i];
             if (sumA > rightS){
                 rightS = sumA;
                 leftIndex = i;
             }
         }

         int crossingSum = leftS+rightS;
         return crossingSum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `middle + 1` in the recursive call never allow the array size to be 1, so the stop condition is never met. Remove the `+ 1`

```
int[] starting = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 0, middle);
int[] ending = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, middle, length);
```